# SendKeys, сочетание Ctrl+A не всегда срабатывает, как бороться?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.

В блоке кода:

```
// Нажимаем Tab
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
// Задержка
Thread.Sleep(200);
// Отправляем Ctrl+A
SendKeys.SendWait("^(a)");
// Задержка
Thread.Sleep(200);
// Отправляем Delete
SendKeys.SendWait("{DELETE}");
// Задержка
Thread.Sleep(200);
```

через раз срабатывает сочетание клавиш Ctrl+A: SendKeys.SendWait("^(a)");

С чем это может быть связано? Как с этим бороться?

p.s. дело не в задержке.

Comment: А фокус находится там, где вы ожидаете?

Comment: @VladD, да, фокус в положенном месте. После нажатия TAB фокус переходит на текстовое поле. И вместо выделения всего текста в поле - печатается буква "а".

Comment: Операция повторяется много раз, я уж и буфер обмена чистил - не помогает. После перезагрузки и перекомпиляции - так стабильно сочетание клавиш не срабатывает. Через несколько перекомпиляций может и сработать, потом опять не работает. Уже и не знаю, в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: А целевое приложение ваше? Можете посмотреть, что приходит в WindowProc?

Comment: Нет, целевое приложение не мое, написано на Delphi, исходников нету.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю, помогло. Когда полностью ушел в прогу - не видишь простых вариантов решения проблемы. Пометьте как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [этот пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750582%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) использует

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^{HOME}");   // Move to start of control
SendKeys.SendWait("^+{END}");   // Select everything
SendKeys.SendWait("{DEL}");     // Delete selection
```

Это, конечно, лишь workaround, но поскольку неясно, на что именно полагается целевая программа для того, чтобы отличить `A` от `Ctrl-A` (например, на [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?), без перебора вариантов и поиска работающего, хоть и теоретически ненадёжного, боюсь, не обойтись.